# Read a file in NuSMV

Tags: file, nusmv

I want to implement a transition system in NuSMV which is specified in a .txt file which I want the tool to read and then build the TS from it.
The file format is :

6

1 2

2 3

3 4

4 5

5 6

This is a particular example where 6 is the total number of vertices/nodes, followed by tuples that specify edges among them. I have looked through some examples in NuSMV but am not getting any relevant example for reading a file describing a transition system. Can anybody help?

Comment: can you give some hints/tips to do that?

Comment: they are specifying the model in the code. I want to read it from a file. That is a prime requirement. Can you tell me if any other model checker supports this?

Comment: ok, no issues! cheers